# Fetching image from Firebase FireStore into carousel Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, slider, carousel

Hi everyone I am referring on YouTube video on displaying images in carousel from firestore in flutter mobile app. However there are some problems that i couldnt solve. Hope anyone can kindly help me for my school project. Thanks!

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BannerSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BannerSliderState createState() => _BannerSliderState();
}

class _BannerSliderState extends State<BannerSlider> {
  int _index = 0;
  int _dataLength = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getSliderImageFromDb();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getSliderImageFromDb() async {
    var _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore.collection('Banner').get();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _dataLength = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
    return snapshot.docs;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          if (_dataLength != 0)
            FutureBuilder(
              future: getSliderImageFromDb(),
              builder: (_, snapShot) {
                return snapShot.data == null
                    ? Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      )
                    : Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                        child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                            itemCount: snapShot.data!.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index, int) {
                              DocumentSnapshot sliderImage =
                                  snapShot.data![index];
                              Map getImage = sliderImage.data();
                              return SizedBox(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: Image.network(
                                    getImage['image'],
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  ));
                            },
                            options: CarouselOptions(
                                viewportFraction: 1,
                                initialPage: 0,
                                autoPlay: true,
                                height: 150,
                                onPageChanged:
                                    (int i, carouselPageChangedReason) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _index = i;
                                  });
                                })),
                      );
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The errors are:

1. snapShot.data![index];

```
Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                                  snapShot.data![index];
                                                ^
```

2.snapShot.data.length,

```
Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.
                            itemCount: snapShot.data!.length,
                                                      ^^^^^^
```

I have try any suggestion by adding null check but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's `data` used to be a property of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, but now it is a function, `data()`.

Since `data()` is a method/function now, you have to add `()` parenthesis.

---

Error 1 -

**Change this**

```
snapShot.data![index];
```

**into**

```
snapShot.data()![index];
```

---

Error 2 -

**Change this**

```
snapShot.data!.length
```

**into**

```
snapShot.data()!.length
```

Comment: The `data` property in both of the changes is actually the property under class `AsyncSnapshot` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html not the one under `QueryDocumentSnapshot`

Comment: Hi Peter @Peter , this property is even valid under `queryDocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the errors are still the same

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
  Future getSliderImageFromDb() async {
    var _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore.collection('Banner').get();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _dataLength = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
```

into this:

```
  Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getSliderImageFromDb() async {
    var _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> snapshot = await _fireStore.collection('Banner').get();
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _dataLength = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
    return snapshot.docs;
  }
```

`QuerySnapshot` now takes a generic parameter for example `Map<String,dynamic>` and since you are return `snapshot.docs` then you also need to specify the type of object you are returning for example `Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>>`

---

Then change:

```
builder: (_, snapShot) {
```

into this:

```
builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> snapShot) {
```

specifying the generic type of this future. In the code you are using the `snapShot` is of type `AsyncSnapshot<Object>` and that's why you get the error:

> Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

---

Then also change:

```
 DocumentSnapshot sliderImage = snapShot.data![index];
```

into this:

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> sliderImage = snapShot.data![index];
```

check:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/CHANGELOG.md#200

Comment: Hi I have tried this method but there are error at <QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> which is The type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.

Comment: The code you suggested there is red curly underline on every <QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> . When i hover on that, this is the problem message i got: The type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given

Comment: Update firestore latest version in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

try this `function`:

```
Future<dynamic> postImageFile(
    {@required File imageFile, @required String folderPath}) async {
  String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  StorageReference reference =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(folderPath).child(fileName);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageFile);
  StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
  print(storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
  return storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

is the best way to get images from `firestore`

Answer (score 0):

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:carousel_slider

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

I have solved all the errors and now getting the error with package:carousel_slider ^2.3.1
I have used the latest, but it's ignoring all the code. If someone knows about this, please contribute